# jQuery AJAX multiple content types doesn't appear to be working

Tags: jquery, ajax

In the jQuery Docs, it mentions that [one can use multiple `dataType`s in a `jQuery.ajax()` request](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (datatype section). This fits well for what I am trying to do, but it's not working as expected for me. It's still parsing the response with the JSON parser but is failing out before it can handle the response as plaintext, like the configuration should require it to. here is my code:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    dataType: "jsonp html",
    url: "http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov:9090/dods/rap/rap20120821/rap_f01.ascii?ugrdprs[7][0][-364][716]",
    success: function( data ) {
        console.log(data);
        callback(null, 'ucb');
    },
});
```

And that successfully gets the file, according to to the Network tab in the Chrome Inspector, but it gives me the error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

instead of getting it like jsonp and converting it to html.

Any idea what could be wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: I didn't understand what you want. The data is being retrieved, but a exception in being thrown? Using only jsonp works? Where is the definition of your jsonp callback? What is being retrieved?

Comment: The url you are trying to retrieve returns a server error

Answer (score 0):

JSONP has 
adds an extra `"?callback=?"` to the end of your URL to specify the callback.

for example if you call

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/XZQFBbdOLRQ?v=2&alt=json

You can see pure json.

However if you call 
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/XZQFBbdOLRQ?v=2&alt=json&callback=jQuery1234

Your data is in **jQuery1234( ... )**

And then, jquery would parse the data  in **jQuery1234( ... )**

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

So are xml and html

if you call 
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/XZQFBbdOLRQ?v=2&callback=jQuery1234

(The Link above would show xml data in **jQuery1234( ... )**)

If you want to convert jsonp data into html
Here is my suggestion:

http://example.com/?callback=jQuery1234

The example response:

```
jQuery1234("<html><head></head><body>Hello World!</body></html>");
```

if you set dataType as  "jsonp html ",
jquery would see your response as html.

Comment: Ugh. I thought xml didn't have to wrap the response. I have no control over the response from the server (it is a legitimate datasource, just for a DAP protocol, not a web friendly one)

Comment: What a pity....
If you still want to get response from other sites, you must need a server to fetch them.

Comment: It's cool, I'll just go with node.js for the project. Its http module does well.